# jquery ajax response in html form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have send query ajax request to server. The server response in two variable that is `errmsg` or `successmsg` . so how can i understand response is whether `errmsg` or `successmsg`. More code explain below

script.js

```
$.ajax({
    url:"abc.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:$('#form').serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        ?????????
    }
    error:function(data){
        .......                     
    }
});
```

abc.php

```
<?php
if (condition) {
    $successmsg = hello;
    echo "$successmsg";
}
elseif (condition) {
    $errmsg = Error Occured;
    echo "$errmsg";
}
elseif (condition) {
    $successmsg = welcome;
    echo "$successmsg";
}
else {
    $errmsg = Bye;
    echo "$errmsg";
}
?>
```

Comment: please provide code for more explaination

Comment: What does the server do?  Does it have documentation that explains these messages?  Your question needs a lot more detail.

Comment: Provided information is too less to understand, what or how you are trying it.

Comment: please add some of your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

return error or success depending on what you are doing with your code in php for example

```
return iferror ? ['errmsg' = 'Error'] : ['successmsg'=>'success'];
```

then get your response in ajax like

```
$.ajax({
       url : 'your-url,
       data : {your - data},
       success: function(response){
            if(response.successmsg){
                console.log(response.successmsg);
              }
            else{
               console.log(response.errmsg);
           },
       error: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can return the server's response using this code:

```
<?php
  if ($textvar > 500){
    echo 'SUCCESS';
  }else{
    echo 'ERROR';
  }
?>
```

Then the `Ajax` code can be:

```
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: '/js/checkmsgs.php',
success: function(res){ // This will be applied if the php code is completlly done without any programming mistakes.
if (res == 'SUCCESS'){
alert('Success');
}else{
alert('Error !');
}
},
error: function(){ // this one will be applied if the php code have a mistake !
alert('eeeeeerrror');
}
});
```